# Books on algebraic groups over C with examples

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, books

I've been trying to learn about algebraic groups lately and I was wondering if there were any books/notes out there which: A. treat algebraic groups over the complex numbers, B. cover all the most frequently encountered buzzwords (reductive, semisimple, borel, levi, cartan, weyl, weights, roots...), C. have many worked out examples.

I only know of Fulton-Harris and Onischik-Vinberg, but I was wondering if there others out there (for whatever reason, I find both a tough read).

Comment: The point with algebraic groups is precisely that the theory (including all that concerns your buzzwords) is the same for all algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero....! Take Springer or Borel (or any other) and replace the field with the complex field, if you feel more comfortable.

Comment: @YCor but which of those books would you recommend?

Comment: I strongly disagree with closing this question as a "duplicate". First of all, the OP asked for references which specifically treat algebraic groups in characteristic zero which is not at all the same as elementary. In characteristic zero one can do things one cannot even dream of in positive characteristic (complete reducibility, slice theorem etc.) Secondly, the purported duplicate is 7 years old and there do exist new books on the market, like Goodman-Wallach. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop you can still contribute to the older question to mention recent books